# data.table, apply function to portion of a table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to apply function to portion of a table.

With data.frame, no problem:

```
df <- data.frame(name = paste("a", 1:10, sep = "-"),
                 x = 1:10,
                 y = rep(1:5),
                 z = rep(1:2, each = 5))

df[2:5, -1] <- scale(df[2:5, -1], center = c(1,2,3), scale = c(4,5,6))
```

But data.table complains:

```
dt <- data.table(name = paste("a", 1:10, sep = "-"),
                 x = 1:10,
                 y = rep(1:5),
                 z = rep(1:2, each = 5))


dt[2:5, -1] <- scale(dt[2:5, -1], center = c(1,2,3), scale = c(4,5,6))
```

> Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, 2:5, -1, value = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75,  :
> Item 1 of column numbers in j is -1 which is outside range [1,ncol=4]. Use column names
> instead in j to add new columns.

What is the correct way in data.table?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data.table` needs more work to apply `scale` :

```
library(data.table)

cols <- names(dt)[-1]
dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = cols]
dt[2:5, (cols) := Map(scale, .SD, c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6)), .SDcols = cols]
```

Comment: Thanks!  I did not know this "(cols)" usage.